# From regression to classification : transform floats to categories

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data

I have an array with the age of a list of people :
`[41, 50, 12, ... , 94]`

I would like to map those onto `20` categories. Is there a way to automatically detects the best categories from the list ( `[15,20,22,24,28,.., 90]` for instance ?) and then map the existing array on it.

Comment: "Best" is entirely subjective. What have you tried based on your on research? How would _you_ split the numbers if you were doing it by hand? Quartiles, standard deviations, clustering algorithms, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas cut function and it will map the ages to the right bin:

```
import pandas as pd
ages = [41, 50, 12, 78,43, 94]
bin_edges = [0,10,15,20,30,50,70,100]
pd.cut(ages,bin_edges)
```

Comment: to be complete I had to get the `bins` and then convert each ages with a lambda function `lambda x : (bins[x] + bins[x+1])/2`